# Thx import XXX cannot be resolved in VSCode for a JAVA project with Gradle

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle

I'm trying to work on the "Iceberg" [repository](https://github.com/apache/iceberg/) with VSCode but even if I install the JAVA jdk + the VSCode extensions for Java and Gradle i'm still having errors like this one

[image]

I also noted this line in the build.gradle file

[image]

Note that if i run `gradlew build` that works it's just not working when working with VSCode but i'd like to be able to run some unit tests easily.

Comment: What folder do you open as a workspace? Execute the command `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` and restart vscode to try.

Comment: I open the root folder of the project. Even after running this command i have the same errors